# Random points in sphere following density curve

Tags: geometry, random, density-function

I want to generate a series of points in a sphere following a density curve (x is distance to sphere center, y is quantity of point at this distance) and I have no idea where to begin with.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. A sphere is a two dimension surface whose distance to center is a constant. Do you mean you have a ball of radius $R$, a function $f(r) : [0,R] \to \mathbb{R}$ and you want to generate a bunch of random points inside the ball so that the probability for a point to fall within the small box $[x,x+\Delta x]\times[y,y+\Delta y]\times[z+\Delta z]$ is proportional to $f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z$.

Comment: I think this answers my question but I'm not a hundred percent sure. I want to generate random points inside of a sphere so that the points density follows a curve. If the curve is a log(n) that means there will be fewer points generated at the center of the sphere and the further you go from the center